# Is there any downside to storing an API key in a browser cookie?

Tags: javascript, api, security

We've got an app with a json API. We use Javascript in the browser to send ajax calls to it. Each API call requires an API key.

I was planning to implement a login API that would accept a username and password and return the API key for that particular user. The key would go in a cookie and get passed back with every API request. (You would still be able to include it in the json request; the cookie would be a fallback.)

The big benefit of this scheme is that we wouldn't need to maintain sessions on the server side. Everything on the server side would be stateless. There's a significant benefit to stateless operation when you're in a clustered environment.

Is this a bad idea? Is it secure? Is there a better way?

Assume that we're running over https.

Comment: Makes the user susceptible to session jacking I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the way you mention, your API keys are not secure this way even though you are using https. That's because the API key now lives on your browser and is susceptible to being exposed either by browser plugins, scripts, etc.

Another thing to consider here is how long are your tokens valid. In such cases it is recommended to have a short API token expiration time.

Fortunately, a lot of people have the same requirement and OAuth 2 spec has a Implicit Grant case flow just for the use case you mentioned. You can look at that and decide your approach,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need support for older browsers, and you only need access to the api key client side, then you can use Local Storage instead, that way you wont have to send a cookie to and from the server, and theres no cookie that can be stolen.

Comment: You still can steal it via XSS or by sniffing the api request. Not much difference to the cookie approach, it just won't be send to the pages not requiring the key.